# R, Json, Rest API

Tags: r, json, rest, post

I'm trying to pull the data from reports in the database using Rest API service POST method available from an R script as below.

```
#Loading Libraries
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

r <- POST(url, 
          body = '{  
          "id":104106,                                                                         
          "lookupName": "Task Report",
          "filters": [ 
          {
          "name":"Created Time",
          "values": ["2018-05-06T00:00:00+0530","2018-05-06T23:59:59+0530"]
          }
          ]}' ,
          add_headers("ApplicationName : APP_1")
)

stop_for_status(r)
a<-content(r, "text", "application/json", encoding="UTF-8")

df = fromJSON(a, flatten = TRUE)
df$links = NULL
df$count = NULL
df$name = NULL
df$columnNames = NULL
main_df = as.data.frame(df)
```

This script can pull data from "Task Report" (Report name in the database) from the URL where created time is between "2018-05-06 00:00:00" and "2018-05-06 23:59:59". The issue with the script is that the data for the given data range contains more than 30k rows and the Rest API has the limitation of pulling data not more than 10k at a go.

Wanted the script to pull all the data for a given range, need help on how to use a loop in the JSON body to get the same.

Comment: Are there any request limitations?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what request limitations mean

Comment: Like 1k request per hour.

Comment: I did not get your comment. Upon running an R script I want to have all the data for the given date range.

Comment: Since i don't know the structure of the api you are using i am not sure that you can do it on one call. If you can narrow down your given date range you can get less result than 10k. Split your date range into chunks. Like 0-4h 4-8h 8-12h 12-16h 16-20h 20-24h Concat results into one dataframe.

Comment: That is what I'm doing right now, If it is for 1 day this can help. But I wanted to pull the data for a range of dates